# Android studio Date picker is missing the OK button

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, datepicker, dialog

I have a problem with the date picker in android 6.0 Marshmallow.
The problem is a simple one, in landscape mode, i have the OK button missing.
Here are some images to demonstrate the problem. (It works perfectly with the time picker)

The problem on tablet and phone:
[image: The problem on tablet.]
[image: The problem on mobile.]

As you can see, i have a spinner on top, but removing it didn't help.

I dont have that problem on the system itself.Here on setting and set datetime it works fine:
[image: Settings, datetime]

Here is the layout for the date time fragment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/White"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner_date_time_choice"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</Spinner>

<TimePicker
    android:id="@+id/time_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<DatePicker
    android:id="@+id/date_picker"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: have you tried either: manually adding a button that links with the datePicker, or adding an onDateChangedListener?

Comment: I want to avoid adding the button because i am using the standard android date picker that has it already. and this works on kitkat properly and it works in portrait mode. I haven't tested it on other versions. Same thing with onDateChangedListener, the ok button is the perfect solution, and it should work, so i want it if possible.